# Dynamic Android interface

Tags: android, dynamic, android-fragments, widget

I'm new to Android and I'm playing around with the sample code at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

If I want to update the article fragment (currently only a TextView) to include more elements dynamically, how do I do it?

Do I need to convert the article.xml to a layout first?

Maybe someone has a good bit of sample code for generating interfaces dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I can understand right you want to add more UI elements to the existing layout...

You need to define an id for the layout in which you want to put in the elements..

say for example..

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/myView";
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

you reference this in the code like so in the onCreate like so..

```
LinearLayout myDynamicView = (LinearLayout)findVivewById(R.id.myView);
```

so if you want to add elements dynamically you can just create them programmatically  and add to the view like so..

```
TextView myExtraView = new TextView(this);
myExtraView.setText("added this programmatically");
myDynamicView.addView(myExtraView);
```

you can add other elements as well...
your question is not very clear but based on what i;ve understood this is what you want.
just search for adding views dynamically in the search bar.

Comment: That's exactly what I want! Thanks! Just one more question. Can I define the layout of the new view you made in an XML? In other words define an instance of an existing view and add it to my layout.

Comment: You could I guess..i havent tried it yet..maybe you can report the results for the community.. :)